# Turtlebot never moves during "Sending goal" with frontier_exploration

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, frontier-exploration, gmapping, turtlebot-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Different issue from http://answers.ros.org/question/196189/frontier_exploration-with-turtlebot/

Using [a package I just made](https://github.com/130s/turtlebot_samples/tree/indigo), which launches Gazebo, gmapping, and nodes from `frontier_exploration` by the following command:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_samples exploration_all.launch
```

Turtlebot stands still while I believe I give a goal point successfully (BTW [I've added a step-by-step instruction for running a demo](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/frontier_exploration?action=diff&rev2=43&rev1=41)).

```
[ INFO] [1465966486.877459779, 0.553000000]: Using plugin "static"
[ INFO] [1465966486.959412012, 0.627000000]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1465966490.228531000, 3.765000000]: Laser is mounted upwards.
 -maxUrange 6 -maxUrange 8 -sigma     0.05 -kernelSize 1 -lstep 0.05 -lobsGain 3 -astep 0.05
 -srr 0.01 -srt 0.02 -str 0.01 -stt 0.02
 -linearUpdate 0.5 -angularUpdate 0.436 -resampleThreshold 0.5
 -xmin -1 -xmax 1 -ymin -1 -ymax 1 -delta 0.05 -particles 80
[ INFO] [1465966490.231561648, 3.767000000]: Initialization complete
update frame 0
update ld=0 ad=0
Laser Pose= -0.0869791 0.0474907 0.00146067
m_count 0
Registering First Scan
[ INFO] [1465966490.300927799, 3.834000000]: Resizing costmap to 288 X 480 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1465966490.399388756, 3.934000000]: Received a 288 X 480 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1465966490.405104350, 3.940000000]: Using plugin "explore_boundary"
[ INFO] [1465966490.518579672, 4.043000000]: Using plugin "sensor"
[ INFO] [1465966490.523587916, 4.048000000]:     Subscribed to Topics: laser
[ INFO] [1465966490.589479815, 4.110000000]: Using plugin "inflation"
[ WARN] [1465966511.346433533, 24.659000000]: Please select an initial point for exploration inside the polygon
[ INFO] [1465966514.076453670, 27.361000000]: Sending goal
```

[image: image description]

I'm guessing something in my config for `frontier_exploration` maybe specific to Turtlebot, but not sure. I'm looking at [frontier_exploration/launch/global_map.launch](https://github.com/paulbovbel/frontier_exploration/blob/3988885f4e4db737f31a1ab12d0aff91f12c76d0/launch/global_map.launch) and [husky_navigation/launch/exploration.launch](https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/indigo-devel/husky_navigation/launch/exploration.launch) in particular.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237001/turtlebot-never-moves-during-%22sending-goal%22-with-frontier_exploration/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2016-06-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`move_base` was not running. I fixed it in [this PR](https://github.com/130s/turtlebot_samples/pull/1).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0